# Should JSON-schema require documents to declare `$schema` (be self-referential)?

Tags: json, jsonschema

JSON-schema says that a JSON document can declare the schema to which the document conforms using [the `$schema` property](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor22). Example:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://example.com/example_fancy_schema#",
    "example_fancy_property": "cute fluffy kittens"
}
```

where the schema looks like:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Example Fancy Schema",
    "description": "The schema that describes the example format.",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "example_fancy_property": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["cute fluffy kittens"]
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": [ "example_fancy_property" ]
}
```

Does this mean that one should add a property for this in the actual schema, e.g.:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Example Fancy Schema",
    "description": "The schema that describes the example format.",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "$schema": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["http://example.com/example_fancy_schema#"]
        },
        "example_fancy_property": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["cute fluffy kittens"]
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": [ "$schema", "example_fancy_property" ]
}
```

None of the examples on the JSON-schema website appear to declare this, so I suspect one isn't supposed to declare it. But I'm curious anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$schema` keyword is *recommended* for use in JSON Schemas, to denote the version of the schema standard being used.

However, it has **no special meaning** in data.  Over HTTP, there are [recommended ways](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor33) to associate data with a schema, but the `$schema` property is not one of them.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Looking at the spec again I'm not sure where I got that idea in the first place. It's too bad that there's not some way to declare this in the actual json document

Comment: Yeah - a convention like `$schema` in the data would be pretty cool.  Unfortunately, the JSON Schema specification doesn't really have the authority to reserve a property name in all JSON documents.

Comment: Wouldn't need to do that as such references are advisory only. e.g. it would suggest to an editor what schema to use, not that a client need reject a document not conforming with said schema. Oh well :)